# Aptana - black color of window (not editors!)

Tags: ide, aptana, color-scheme

I have a question. Is it possible to turn black Aptana Studio 3 window frames, options menu and such? There is no much difference if you use black themes, if everything around is still grey. I am working on Win 7, and even using another theme color on OS not changing colors in Aptana.